# What is the best way to create a react application with rails backend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

I have a rails application and i want to use react for the front end. Could anyone suggest what will be the best way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails ?

Comment: Yes, I have. But as i was using rails 4.2.2, i am getting a lot of issues with gems. Do i need to upgrade my rails version and the ruby version too ?

Comment: That's your choice, probably it depends how hard is to do the bump. But if you can - do it :) Overall you can use built-in rails features, you can include react explicite (without using rails), you can also set a separable standalone react app and just use rails as an api. All depends on the context :)